# number of irreps quotient by a nontrivial normal subgroup.

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Let $n$ be a number of irreps of the group $G$. Let $H$ be a nontrivial normal subgroup of $G$. Let $h$ be  number of irreps of the group $G/H.$ Prove that $$n>h$$

I assume that this has something to do with the fundamental theorem on homomorphisms. But I do not  manage to use it. I have no idea how to start it.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you know that each irreducible representation on the quotient induces an irreducible representation on $G$? and that distinct representation of the quotient induce distinct representations of $G$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was put very well in the comment, however I will explicate further in case that was too terse as I feel that the answer to this question is very enlightening when it comes to the basics of representation theory. Given a group $G$, a normal subgroup $H \trianglelefteq G$, one has the homomorphism $\pi: G \to G/H$. Now if one has some $\rho: G/H \to GL_n(\mathbb C)$ then composing the two homomorphisms $\rho \circ \pi: G \to GL_n(\mathbb C)$ gives a representation $\hat{\rho}$ of $G$. Further, if we take $\rho$ to be irreducible then $\hat{\rho}$ is STILL irreducible because $\pi$ is an epimorphism (surjective homomorphism).

So we have that $n \geq h$, all we need to do is show that there is some irreducible representation of $G$ that is not induced by one of $G/H$. Now there are a couple ways to do this, one is to note that there cannot be an element $g \in G$ such that $\rho(g) = I$ for all $\rho$ irreducible, and combine that with the fact that $\pi$ must have nontrivial kernel. An easier way is to note that the sum of the squares of the dimensions of the irreducible representations of a group must be the order of that group. Since all of the $\hat{\rho}$ have the same degree as $\rho$, and $G$ is bigger than $G/H$ we know that there must be more irreducible representations.

I think the first paragraph in particular provides a lot of insight into the types of proofs that show up in and intro course on the representation theory of finite groups, and moreover why this statement should be true.

Comment: As you probably know: one quick way to fill out your comment on finding a $\rho$ such that $\rho(g) \neq I$ is to note that the regular rep. of $G$ is faithful, so for any non-trivial $g \in G$, at least one irreducible summand of the regular rep. is non-trivial on $g$.  This is logically easier than using the result on sums of squares (which involves completely analyzing the structure of the regular rep, rather than just appealing to its faithfulness); of course, if we take the sum of squares formula as given, then (as you say) its certainly easier just to apply it!

Comment: The statement on the sum of squares of dimensions of irreps is nothing more than the semi-simplicity of K[G] combines with the observation that the regular representation is faithful so I don't think it's that much of a swindle to use that result, but you are correct that technically all that is required is the weaker statement.

Comment: "Is nothing more than ..."; you also need Frob. rec. applied to the reg. rep, but I agree it's not hard.

Comment: Hmm, isn't it just that $dim(Hom_G(V_i, R)) = \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g} \chi_{V_i}(g)\chi_{R}(g)$ and the realization that $\chi_R(g) = 0$ for $g \neq 1$ (R = k[G])? I don't see where Frobenius rec. happens here. But I think I remember the idea that you're thinking of.

Comment: Yes, you're right, but I wasn't thinking of it that way.  I was rather thinking of $$Hom_G(V_i,R) = Hom_G(V_i, Ind_{\{1\}}^G \mathbb C) = Hom(V_i, \mathbb C) = V_i^{\vee},$$  the last isomorphism being a case of Frob. rec.   I think this just reflects my preference/prejudice for arguing with the reps. themselves rather than their characters.  I'll stop bothering you at this point!